I am confused in javascript shallow copy
'a' array wasn't affected.
const a = [1,2,3]
const b = [...a] // shallow copy

b[0] = 9

console.log(a) // [1,2,3]
console.log(b) // [9,2,3] results as expected


----------

const a = [{name:"John"},{name:"George"}];
const b = [...a];

b[0] = {name:"Oliver"}

console.log(a) // [ { name: 'John' }, { name: 'George' } ]
console.log(b); // [ { name: 'Oliver' }, { name: 'George' } ] results as expected


----------

const a = [{name:"John"},{name:"George"}];
const b = [...a];

b[0].age = 21

console.log(a); //[ { name: 'John', age: 21 }, { name: 'George' } ]
console.log(b); // [ { name: 'John', age: 21 }, { name: 'George' } ]


// why were affected 'a' array ?
Why were they both affected? It shows the same reference, but in the other 2 examples above, there was no change, only the 'b' array changed.

In the first examples, you did not change anything inside the object elements of the arrays. Shallow copy means that only the values in the array are copied, one level deep. So the object references are copied, but new constituent objects are not created. That would be a "deep" copy.

Basically, you have a wrong question. In the third example, the a array is not affected. a still has exactly the same contents before b[0].age = 21 and after it: the John object, and the George object. It is just now we know John's age. It is only the John object being affected by that statement.

It happens because the reference of the object is not changing, internally when you make a shallow copy of the "a" array, you are making a copy of a reference to those objects, so after changing b[0] object you are also affecting a[0] since its the same object

In the second example, you assigned b[0] to totally new object ( with new referance ), but in the third example, you changed the age in the object with reference shared between both a and b arrays.
If you need the same behavior you need to map new references.


const a = [{name:"John"},{name:"George"}];
const b = [...a.map(o => ({...o}))];

b[0].age = 21

console.log(a); //[ { name: 'John' }, { name: 'George' } ]
console.log(b); // [ { name: 'John', age: 21 }, { name: 'George' } ]



Here [...a.map(o => ({...o}))] will replace all the objects inside a array with a new copy but with a different reference.
Update 
Or as shared by @Andy and @Amadan, you can use structuredClone to deep clone the array.


const a = [{name:"John"},{name:"George"}];
const b = structuredClone(a);

b[0].age = 21

console.log(a); //[ { name: 'John' }, { name: 'George' } ]
console.log(b); // [ { name: 'John', age: 21 }, { name: 'George' }




There is also structuredClone.

Or, simply const b = structuredClone(a). JS has come a long way :)

@Andy Amadan, I didn't know about this method, thanks for sharing.
